# MVC Custom Validation against List

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a List Which i am checking within my Custom Validation attribute. List Renders like this on my VIEW

```
<input type="check" value="Bath">
<input type="check" value="Food">
```

and my Custom Validator is...

```
public class MyAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
  // some logic and then
  // Get Data from some webservice 
  // Make sure CERTAIN checkboxes are selected
  // If Bath was NOT checked then
  return new ValidationResult("Bath is Required")
  // If Food was NOT checked then
  return new ValidationResult("Food is Required")
}
```

Now this works fine & I can show the error message "**Some Error**" on my view, However my issue is I want to show the **RED ERROR BOX** around the checkbox which was REQUIRED to check. Currently i am just showing a Error message string on my VIEW. It would be nice for user to see what was REQUIRED.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a style attribute as the 3rd Argument to the ValidationMessageFor method in razor view as such:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.StudentName, "", new { @style="color:red" })
```

You can also run your application trigger the validation message, in chrome, right click the validation message and inspect element, go to the debugger window and trace the class associated with the validation error message.

Go to site.css and overwrite the default validation-error message class as shown below:

```
    span.field-validation-error {
        background-color: #ffeeee;
        outline: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

Hope this will help.